# Char array initialisation in class

Tags: c++, arrays, cppunit

I am trying to unit test a C++ application that I am building and I'm having an issue initializing the array when used in a class. I've tried alot of different methods of loading this information, the only ones that work are inefficient / not suitable.

Here is the hex array that I have (randomised the parts)

```
0x24,0x54,0x3b,0x72,0x8b,0x03,0x24,0x29,0x23,0x43,0x66,0x22,0x53,0x41,0x11,0x62,0x10
```

And header file for my unit test:

```
class MessageParsingTest : public CPPUNIT_NS::TestFixture {
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE(MessageParsingTest);

    CPPUNIT_TEST(testIdentifyFirstMessageType);

    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_END();

public:
    MessageParsingTest();
    virtual ~MessageParsingTest();
    void setUp();
    void tearDown();

private:
    void testIdentifyFirstMessageType();
    void testIdentifySecondMessageType();

    // data members for the hex array
    unsigned char firstMessage[1500]; 
};
```

Then in my test case setUp function;

```
void MessageParsingTest::setUp() {
    firstMessage = {0x24,0x54,0x3b,0x72,0x8b,0x03,0x24,0x29,0x23,0x43,0x66,0x22,0x53,0x41,0x11,0x62,0x10};
}
```

That it my latest failed attempt, it says its not valid during compilcation, as I expected, but at this point I was trying anything.

I've also tried things like (all in setUp function)

```
firstMessage << "\0x24\0x54\0x3b\0x72\0x8b\0x03\0x24\0x29\0x23\0x43\0x66\0x22\0x53\0x41\0x11\0x62\0x10";

firstMessage[1500] = "\0x24\0x54\0x3b\0x72\0x8b\0x03\0x24\0x29\0x23\0x43\0x66\0x22\0x53\0x41\0x11\0x62\0x10";
```

and a few other crazy ways, Does anyone know the proper way to load this data? the only way I've had it working so far is with either no data member declaration and straight up defining it and initializing in one line (but then I cant access in the test cases) or doing it one by one like `firstMessage[0] = 0x24;` etc.

I understand that there will be a simple, proper way of doing this and considering what the application actually does, this part should be the easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few options:

1. Initialize arrays in constructor MesssageParsingTest using syntax : `firstMessage{0x24,0x54,0x3b,0x72,0x8b,0x03,0x24,0x29,0x23,0x43,0x66,0x22,0x53,0x41,0x11,0x62,0x10}`
   in initializer list.
2. Create static const array containing your message, and either copy it to member variable using memcpy, or use static member and get rid of firstMessage member variable.

Declare const static member in .h inside class definition:

```
static const unsigned char kFirstMessage[];
```

and define + initialize it in .ccp

```
const unsigned char MessageParsingTest::kFirstMessage[] = "\0x24\0x54\0x3b\0x72\0x8b\0x03\0x24\0x29\0x23\0x43\0x66\0x22\0x53\0x41\0x11\0x62\0x10";
```

I would prefer static const member if you do not intend to modify this array later, since it makes the intention cleaner.

Comment: I tried method 1. first of all and it worked when I added `-std=c++0x` to the compiler options, Option 2 never worked though but seemed more appealing, Am I right in adding this line in the class definition in the header file?

Comment: @llya thanks for your help. but im getting an error with this static method, when doing `const unsigned char MessageParsingTest::kFirstMessage[] = ...` in the constructor it tells me "error: definition or redeclaration of kFirstMessage not allowed inside a function". I enjoy working in C\C++ but sometimes the simplest of things can be a right pain!

Comment: Since this is a static class member, definition has to be outside of the function body - in the same scope as class methods are defined.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it.

```
void MessageParsingTest::setUp()
{
    unsigned char x[] = {0x24,0x54,0x3b,0x72,0x8b,0x03,0x24,0x29,0x23,0x43,0x66,0x22,0x53,0x41,0x11,0x62,0x10};
    ::memcpy(firstMessage, x, sizeof(x));
}
```

If you are using C++11, you can also initialize the firstMessage in the class member initialization list as

```
MessageParsingTest::MessageParsingTest() : 
   firstMessage{0x24,0x54,0x3b,0x72,0x8b,0x03,0x24,0x29,0x23,0x43,0x66,0x22,0x53,0x41,0x11,0x62,0x10},
   ...
```

Comment: Thank you, Your second method and the reference to c++11 worked. I'm going to try the static const method below as I think that would be more suitable

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary buffer and then copy into you member as this:

```
void MessageParsingTest::setUp() {
    unsigned char tmp[1500] = {0x24,0x54,0x3b,0x72,0x8b,0x03,0x24,0x29,0x23,0x43,0x66,0x22,0x53,0x41,0x11,0x62,0x10};
    memcpy(firstMessage, tmp, 1500);
}
```